# Weird exception from PreferencesActivity

Tags: android

I made some edits to my preferences.xml file, nothing that generated any syntax flags in Eclipse, and now I'm getting the following weird error when I try to inflate my PreferencesActivity:

E/AndroidRuntime( 3480): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity Co
mponentInfo{com.shipmate/com.shipmate.PreferencesActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArg
umentException: Cannot add a PreferenceCategory directly to a PreferenceCategory

I always have PreferenceCategory's inside other PreferenceCategory's so I don't think that's the problem. What does it mean that it thinks I'm "adding" one PreferenceCategory to another? What does "add" mean in XML? And how does an IllegalArgument relate to this addition? Any ideas on how I might isolate this problem?

Comment: Can you show the xml from your preferences activity?

Answer (score 2):

> I always have PreferenceCategory's
>   inside other PreferenceCategory's so I
>   don't think that's the problem.

By my reading of the Android source code, `PreferenceCategory` cannot be an immediate child of `PreferenceCategory`. Moreover, you should never need that, since that has no visual benefit -- have the `PreferenceCategory` elements be peers of each other in the XML, not nested.

> What does it mean that it thinks I'm
>   "adding" one PreferenceCategory to
>   another?

Uh, that seems pretty self-explanatory. You have a `PreferenceCategory`, and you are attempting to put another `PreferenceCategory` inside of it. This is done, whether in code or via inflation, via an `addPreference()` method on `PreferenceGroup`. That in turn calls `onPrepareAddPreference()`, which in `PreferenceCategory` does the category-in-category check and throws your exception.

> And how does an IllegalArgument relate
>   to this addition?

It is the particular flavor of `RuntimeException` that the Android developers chose to use in this case. They could have chosen `DivideByZeroException`, for example, but that would have been rather odd.